# How do you select one radio button out of two when you use javascript in ASP?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

Here's my situation. I have this form here:

```
            <td style="width: 100px">Gender : </td>
            <td style="width: 220px">
                Male <input name="mRadio" type="radio" /> 
                Female <input name="fRadio" type="radio" />
            </td>
```

This is is within a form with other stuff that I'm sending it to an ASP page. What I'm trying to do is get the info on the radio buttons. As such, if the male gender is selected, the female gender is deselected and a variable on the asp page is given "Sir" as its value. Vice verse as well (so the value would be "Miss" if female). I searched but cannot seem to find a proper answer to this question. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

The radio buttons need the same "name" in order for only one to be allowed to be selected and you can set a value for each.

Try this...

```
        <td style="width: 100px">Gender : </td>
        <td style="width: 220px">
            Male <input name="gender" value="Sir" type="radio" /> 
            Female <input name="gender" value="Miss" type="radio" />
        </td>
```

Comment: And obviously in the asp page use the request object to collect the value. ie `Request("gender")`

Comment: But how would I distinguish male from female in the classic asp page?

Comment: You would use "male" instead of "Sir".

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna read the radiobutton as an html control easily you can add the "runat='server'" and in the code behind verify if is checked

Example(html):

```
Male <input id="mRadio" type="radio" runat="server"/> 
Female <input id="fRadio" type="radio" runat="server"/>
```

(asp):

```
If mRadio.Checked = True Then
.
End If
```

Comment: This is classic asp, not .net